# mySql как отправлять в таблицу комы, кавычки?

Tags: mysql, winforms

Записываю в БД каталожные номера товаров и не только. Часто встречаются самые разные символы, такие как комы, кавычки и другие символы, которые ломают запрос. Нужен самый простой и красивый способ экранировать сразу все отправляемые строки.

Пример запроса:

```
MySql.command("INSERT INTO remonts (client_id, name, details, user, price_sum, date_added, date_mod, status) " +
                $"VALUES ('{client_id}','{textBox2.Text}','{richTextBox1.Text}','{comboBox1.Text}','{Regex.Replace(label7.Text, "[а-я.]", "")}','{System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")}','{System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")}','Ожидает ремонта')");
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() или real_escape_string()

Comment: не надо ничего экранировать. параметры в запросы передаются отдельно от тела запроса с использованием плейсхолдеров и биндинга

Comment: Ваш вопрос остался незамеченным, потому что не хватает правильных меток: `c#` и `sql`. / И нужно указать, откуда взят этот метод `MySql.command`? Из какой-то библиотеки? Или он самописный? Тогда нужно привести его код.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, вопрос еще времен, когда только начинал работу с базами данных. Нашел в интернете классный метод, через которую прогоняем строку, и получаем уже экранированную.

Comment: _классный метод_ - нет, это плохой метод. Используйте prepared/parameterized query. Параметры не только полностью снимают проблему кавычек и прочих символов, но и обезопасят от sql-инъекций и повысят производительность.